# How to store data in a table using openxml with While loop in SQL for multiple XMLs

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, openxml, sql-server-openxml

I have a temp table with 3 XMLs in it:

```
CREATE TABLE #XMLwithOpenXML
(
    Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    XMLData XML,
    LoadedDateTime DATETIME
);
go

INSERT INTO #XMLwithOpenXML(XMLData, LoadedDateTime) 
    SELECT 
        CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
    FROM 
        OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:\Test\Test1.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

INSERT INTO #XMLwithOpenXML(XMLData, LoadedDateTime) 
    SELECT 
        CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
    FROM 
        OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:\Test\Test2.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

INSERT INTO #XMLwithOpenXML(XMLData, LoadedDateTime) 
    SELECT 
        CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
    FROM 
        OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:\Test\Test2.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;
go
```

I'm trying to extract some data from it into another temp table and I'm successful in doing so with the below code:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc as int, @SQL nvarchar(max)

SELECT @XML = XMLData 
FROM #XMLwithOpenXML

SELECT @XML

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

EXEC Rm #DocNameForCapsilonFieldId

SELECT
    DocTypeName = typeName, DataPointName, FieldId = FieldName, ValueData
INTO
    #DocNameForCapsilonFieldId
FROM
    OPENXML(@hDoc, 'documents/document/dataPoints/dataPoint/field/value')
    WITH
        (
            typeName [varchar](256) '../../../../typeName',
            DataPointName [varchar](256) '../../@name',
            FieldName [varchar](256) '../@name',
            ValueData [varchar](256) '../value'
        ) AS DocTypeName

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
go
```

But the problem is that it picks up only the first XML and extracts its data. I want to extract data from all the 3 XMLs and store it in `#DocNameForCapsilonFieldId` or any table in database. I know this is done through While loop but I don't really know how to implement it. Can someone help me out with this or maybe even make this a stored procedure?

Comment: Not that it affects the core of your question, but did you notice that `D:\Test\Test2.xml` is inserted twice?

Comment: @Nitin Deb, please edit your post and share a sample of your XML. Also, what is your SQL Server version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: `FROM OPENXML`, together with the SPs to prepare and to remove a document, is outdated and should not be used any more (rare exceptions exist).

Always try to use the [native XML methods provided by the XML data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-data-type-methods?view=sql-server-ver15). Namely `.nodes()`, to retrieve repeating elements as many rows in a derived set, and `.value()` to fetch scalar values.

This is not really a new answer, more an addition to the answer by @AlwaysLearning.

The *backward navigation* (the parent axis, used in your example with multiple `../`) is performing very badly. Better use cascades of `APPLY` with `.nodes()`, diving deeper and deeper over *realtive XPaths*:

(Credits for DDL and sample: @AlwaysLearning's answer)

```
drop table if exists #XMLwithOpenXML;
create table #XMLwithOpenXML (
  XMLData xml
);
insert #XMLwithOpenXML values
(N'<documents>
 <document>
  <typeName>Example1</typeName>
  <dataPoints>
   <dataPoint name="dp11">
    <field name="foo">
     <value>42</value>
    </field>
   </dataPoint>
   <dataPoint name="dp12">
    <field name="bar">
     <value>47</value>
    </field>
   </dataPoint>
  </dataPoints>
 </document>
</documents>'),
(N'<documents>
 <document>
  <typeName>Example2</typeName>
  <dataPoints>
   <dataPoint name="dp21">
    <field name="baz">
     <value>21</value>
    </field>
   </dataPoint>
   <dataPoint name="dp22">
    <field name="chaz">
     <value>22</value>
    </field>
   </dataPoint>
  </dataPoints>
 </document>
</documents>');
```

--The query:

```
SELECT A.doc.value('(typeName/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS TypeName
      ,B.dp.value('@name','nvarchar(max)') AS DataPoint_Name
      ,C.fld.value('@name','nvarchar(max)') AS Field_Name
      ,C.fld.value('(value/text())[1]','int') AS Field_Value
FROM #XMLwithOpenXML t
CROSS APPLY XMLData.nodes('/documents/document') A(doc)
OUTER APPLY A.doc.nodes('dataPoints/dataPoint') B(dp)
OUTER APPLY B.dp.nodes('field') C(fld);
```

The result

```
TypeName    DataPoint_Name  Field_Name  Field_Value
Example1    dp11            foo         42
Example1    dp12            bar         47
Example2    dp21            baz         21
Example2    dp22            chaz        22
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it without a `WHILE` loop - use a `CROSS APPLY` with `nodes()` and `value()` XML functions instead, e.g. something like the following:

```sql
drop table if exists #DocNameForCapsilonFieldId;
create table #DocNameForCapsilonFieldId (
  DocTypeName nvarchar(256),
  DataPointName nvarchar(256),
  FieldId nvarchar(256),
  ValueData nvarchar(256)
);

drop table if exists #XMLwithOpenXML;
create table #XMLwithOpenXML (
  XMLData xml
);
insert #XMLwithOpenXML values
(N'<documents>
 <document>
  <typeName>Example1</typeName>
  <dataPoints>
   <dataPoint name="dp11">
    <field name="foo">
     <value>42</value>
    </field>
   </dataPoint>
   <dataPoint name="dp12">
    <field name="bar">
     <value>47</value>
    </field>
   </dataPoint>
  </dataPoints>
 </document>
</documents>'),
(N'<documents>
 <document>
  <typeName>Example2</typeName>
  <dataPoints>
   <dataPoint name="dp21">
    <field name="baz">
     <value>21</value>
    </field>
   </dataPoint>
   <dataPoint name="dp22">
    <field name="chaz">
     <value>22</value>
    </field>
   </dataPoint>
  </dataPoints>
 </document>
</documents>');

insert #DocNameForCapsilonFieldId (DocTypeName, DataPointName, FieldId, ValueData)
  select
    x.n.value(N'../../../../typeName[1]', N'nvarchar(256)'),
    x.n.value(N'../../@name[1]', N'nvarchar(256)'),
    x.n.value(N'../@name[1]', N'nvarchar(256)'),
    x.n.value(N'.', N'nvarchar(256)')
  from #XMLwithOpenXML
  cross apply XMLData.nodes(N'documents/document/dataPoints/dataPoint/field/value') x(n);
```

Which yields the results...

```
DocTypeName  DataPointName  FieldId  ValueData
Example1     dp11           foo      42
Example1     dp12           bar      47
Example2     dp21           baz      21
Example2     dp22           chaz     22
```

Comment: Although this might work, it will perform very badly... The *backward navigation* using the parent axis (in your example the various `../`) is a well known killer. Better is a cascade of `.nodes()` diving deeper and deeper into relative paths using multiple `APPLY` calls.

Comment: Hi, I just added a sample for my comment as an answer here, hope this helps the OP too :-)